# Error: Chain.call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

Tags: python, py-langchain

```py
file_path = "example.pdf"  # Path to your input file
with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
    try:
        text = read_file(file)  # Read text from file
        other_variables = {}  # Define other prompt variables
        response = sequential_chain.call(text=text, other_variables=other_variables)
        print(response)  # Process response as needed
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
```

Comment: Modify your question to it could be readable and give some more info on from which module you get sequential_chain function